# Identifying American (Mercury) Mariner outboard

Tags: engine

We have Mariner 9.9E outboard motor. Having hard time figuring out year and Yamaha equivalent (early Mariners were Yamahas in disguise). There is very little information on those, and it is hard to find exact owner and repair manual.

Serial number on the motor starts with 682C, and, according to [this reference](http://continuouswave.com/whaler/reference/yamahaModelGuide.html) it should equate to Yamaha 6E7 model (9.9D) from 1981 on. On Australian Yamaha support site I had found [owner’s manual](http://www.yamahaownershandbook.com.au/lib/download.php?f=6E7-28199-22.pdf) for 9.9D from 1984 (first edition). But I had read that Mariner 9.9E with SN 682C 551*** should be 1981 (hearsay-ish).

1. Is it safe to assume that international Yamaha 9.9D from mid-80s is equivalent to my particular Mariner? Could changes requested by Mercury be significant?
2. Given above, must I seek out specific Mercury or Yamaha service manual (no luck so far), or something like umbrella Seloc would be enough?
3. Is it normal that international 9.9D requires 1:100 oil to fuel ratio as per owner’s manual, and would it be the case in American version?

Answer (score 1):

*In progress.*

Managed to find Clymer repair manual (very broad, 2 to 220 HP, 1977 to 1989) through EBSCO database, it stresses using 1:25 fuel ratio on break-in, and 1:50 thereafter.

Comment: Did that ratio end up working for you?

Comment: @Seminecis, I’m yet to get it to start. :) It’s on the back burner now.

Comment: Just wondering if you ever figured this out?